# can not open the share folder via command openDir

Tags: php

I have problem with command openDir on our network share space

use:

```
openDir( '\\\\172.17.50.8\tsbnb_rw' );
```

and error is below:

```
Warning: opendir(\\172.17.50.8\tsbnb_rw,\\172.17.50.8\tsbnb_rw) [function.opendir]: Access is denied. (code: 5)
```

This share folder needed authorization user and password, but I have no idea how to set this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php

// Define the parameters for the shell command
$location = "\\servername\sharename";
$user = "USERNAME";
$pass = "PASSWORD";
$letter = "Z";

// Map the drive
system("net use ".$letter.": \"".$location."\" ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:no>nul 2>&1");

// Open the directory
$dir = opendir($letter.":/an/example/path")

...

?>
```

Comment: I tried this, but error has been changed
system( "net use Z: \"\\\\172.17.50.8\tsbnb_rw\" parselog /user:parselog /persistent:no>nul 2>&1" );
openDir( "Z:" );

Warning: opendir(Z:,Z:) [function.opendir]: The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in D:\stb_web\www\pe\toshiba.php on line 78

Comment: server path is correct, look the picture http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2eoebnm&s=5#.UlUizFARB20

Comment: I solved the problem... in user name must be the domain domain\\username, tnx

Comment: Glad that you have figured it out.

Comment: Can someone explain what "sharename" is? in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

try reading the manual; for samba under linux, there's an example here:

[opendir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php#83211)